# how to change the language of vue.js 3 website using option tag. (with i18n)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i am working on vue 3 project and i want to have localization on it.
i installed `"vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",` and use below code in my main.js file.

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'


const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    allowComposition: true, 
    messages: {
      en: {
        hello: 'hello!'
      },
      ir: {
        hello: 'سلام'
      }
    }
})
```

with changing the `locale: 'en'` to `locale: 'ir'` every things work well but this is the only way to change the language. actually i want to change language using option tag like this

```
      <select>
        <option value="english" selected>english</option>
        <option value="persian">persian</option>
      </select>
```

do you have any suggestion???

Comment: This is the way to change default locale. It's changed dynamically by setting i18n.locale

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follow. You can also check the [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-lan-change-g3fj99)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selected_language" @change="change_language">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="ir">Persian</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ $t('hello') }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

export default {
  setup() {
    const { locale, t } = useI18n();
    const selected_language = ref(locale.value);

    const change_language = () => {
      // Update the locale based on the selected value
      locale.value = selected_language.value;
    };

    return {
      selected_language,
      change_language,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks my friend. exactly what i wanted. it works correctly